# Can WCF Self-hosting service have initialization logic?

Tags: wcf, initialization, service

I have created a WCF Service Library in VS2010 and can run the service by selecting Debug->Start New Instance from project's right click menu.

Can I further define some initialization logic that would be executed before the service is started?

EDIT:

What I try to achieve is to initialize NHibernate and several other elements so that they are ready when the service starts.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  When you say 'before the service is started', do you mean before you call `Open` on your `ServiceHost`?

Comment: I explained it in the edit in the main post. I don't write my own host application, just take advantage of VS2010 ability to run WCF service defined in project of type 'WCF Servcice Library'.

Comment: Self-host has a specific meaning in WCF, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx  I would recommend changing your title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you self-host (i.e. write your WCF host yourself) - sure, no problem, do whatever you need to do before you call `.Open()` on the `ServiceHost`.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourServiceClass));

// do your initialization here
........

host.Open();
```

If you're using IIS or WAS or AppFabric to host your WCF service: I doubt it, since those are "message-based" activation server, e.g. they start up a service host to handle a request on demand, when a request comes in, and I'm not aware of any extension points to get into the initialization process if you're using the regular `ServiceHost` class for hosting.

That said: you can of course define your own descendants of `ServiceHost` - derive your custom service host from `ServiceHost` or `ServiceHostBase` - those should give you points to get into the initialization process (overriding the `InitializeRuntime` method, or responding to the `Opening` event).

See the MSDN docs on:

- [ServiceHostBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostbase.aspx) abstract base class for custom service hosts
- [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) as a concrete implementation of `ServiceHostBase` to possibly inherit from
- [Custom Service Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx) explaining the ins and outs of how to achieve this all